# Reading data from StreamSocket only works on desktop, not on phone (Universal Windows App)

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, asyncsocket, windows-10-mobile

Having a weird problem with an UWP app I'm trying to create when creating a socket and reading back data from it. Here's the basic scenario:

```
_commandSocket = new StreamSocket();
await _commandSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("192.168.1.1"), "15740", SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);
_commandOutput = _commandSocket.OutputStream;
_commandInput = _commandSocket.InputStream;
await _commandOutput.WriteAsync(initCommandBuffer);
var lengthBytes = new byte[4].AsBuffer();
await input.ReadAsync(lengthBytes, 4, InputStreamOptions.None);
etc..etc...etc...
```

I'm basically opening a socket and sending an initialization command to my device. The idea is that it'll reply by first sending me the length of the reply as an uint.

This all works perfectly well when I debug/run the app on my desktop, but if I try to run this on my Window 10 Mobile device (Nokia 930) it seems not a single byte is being read (I've tried reading 1 byte instead of 4). Since app development should be 'Universal' and it's all working perfectly on my desktop I have no idea where to start fixing this.

Opening the connection on the mobile device works, I'm also not getting any errors when sending the initialization command, it just keeps blocking on the await ReadAsync command (as if nothing is being sent back).

I don't have any influence on the device that I'm connecting to, but again since this is all working flawlessly on the desktop and the device doesn't know who's asking I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: Any chance the remote device only allows one connection at a time (your desktop) and is ignoring the phone? (Try running from another desktop to verify). Also the phone might be trying to use the cell network instead of WiFi (just a guess - try turning off cellular data).

Comment: The device definitely only allows one connection at a time, but there's no other device trying to connect to it. I would also expect an error opening the socket if I wasn't allowed to connect to it. For the same reason I also don't expect that turning of the cell network will make any difference, but I'll try that tonight.

Comment: Dude! That's crazy. Turning off the cell (4G) network only leaving WiFi on did the trick. What I still don't understand now is that with only 4G on and WiFi turned off I can still connect to 192.168.1.1. What am I connecting to in that case!?!? That's a local address on the 4G network??? 1 thing left to do: How can I force my program to make use of the WiFi instead of the 4G connection?

Comment: No idea what I'm connecting to 192.168.1.1 on the 4G network, but using     var profiles = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
var wifiProfile = profiles.ToArray().First(p => p.IsWlanConnectionProfile);
_networkAdapter = wifiProfile.NetworkAdapter; I got the NetworkAdapter which I can pass onto the streamsocket. This can all be done cleaner searching for SSID's or something I guess, but that's something to figure out for later. For now this is solved! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. I have no idea what magic cellular networks use :-)

Answer (score 0):

Cannot confirm my answer for sure, becasue I only tested in on an emulator, but I used stream socket listener.

```
        private async void StartServer()
    {
        int Port = 80;
        try
        {
            //Bound to port 80
            await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(Port.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            //Port 80 for communication is blocked.
        }

        listener.ConnectionReceived += async (s, e) =>
        {
            using (IInputStream input = e.Socket.InputStream)
            {
                var buffer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.Buffer(200);
                await input.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
                //reads incoming stream
                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer.ToArray(), 0, (int) buffer.Length);
            }

            using (IOutputStream output = e.Socket.OutputStream)
            {
                using (Stream response = output.AsStreamForWrite())
                {
                    response.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Response."), 0, 1);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Not seeing how you're doing anything different. I'm also using a streamsocket, but not using the listener since I'm acting as a client not a server.